# User-defined literal string: compile-time length check

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert, compile-time-constant, user-defined-literals

I have a user-defined literal operator that only makes sense for strings of a specific length, like this:

```
constexpr uint16_t operator "" _int(const char* s, std::size_t len)
{
    return len == 2 ? s[0] | (s[1] << 8) : throw;
}
```

This works:

```
"AB"_int // equals 16961
```

But this also compiles, and I don't want it to:

```
"ABC"_int // throws at runtime
```

I tried `static_assert(len == 2)`, but it isn't allowed in a constexpr function.

How can I make `"ABC"_int` cause an error at compile time?

Comment: Use constexpr if with a static assert? Use `len` as a template parameter, and `std::enable_if`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Parameters aren't usable in constant expressions. `constexpr` functions are meant to be usable at both compile time and runtime. There's room for more, but this is all we've got for now.

Comment: If you use the templated UDL extension that clang and g++ support (which is likely to come into future standards), you could do it.

Comment: The argument-less `throw` here is a **rethrow**, which should terminate the program unless one happens to be in a `catch` clause somewhere.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you declare `const size_t len`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++20 you can use `consteval` and a normal `assert` (or whatever exception you like):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

consteval uint16_t operator "" _int(const char* s, size_t len)
{
    assert(len == 2);
    return s[0] | (s[1] << 8);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "AB"_int << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "ABC"_int << std::endl;  // compiler error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tagged the question as C++11 back in 2017 because user-defined literals were introduced in C++11.  I'm happy to see a C++20 solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make `"ABC"_int` cause an error at compile time?

By example: initialize a `constexpr` variable

```
constexpr auto foo = "ABC"_int;
```

Otherwise (if you don't force the compile time calculation in some way) the compiler doesn't compute (not mandatory but, in fact, is what happens) compile time but prepare the code for the run-time compilation.

Comment: @MarkRansom - D'Oh! Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's useful  info that the OP apparently was unaware of, but it's not an answer. It should be a comment; flagged as such.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - It seems to me that respond to the question; clearly if the OP intend "How can I make "ABC"_int cause **ever** an error at compile time?", doesn't give a solution but explain (It seems to me clear) that it's impossible. Waiting for the moderator action.

Comment: I realize that using the value in a `constexpr` will make `"ABC"_int` fail to compile, but I want `"ABC"_int` to fail to compile even if used outside a `constexpr`.  Another way of stating it is that I want the operator to be evaluated as `constexpr` always, and if it can't be, it should fail to compile.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - Sorry: in this form (literal operator for char const * and size) I don't think it's possible (at the moment). If you were interested in numbers (something `12_int` instead of `"AB"_int`) there was the template form for string literal (so, by example, a `static_assert()`). But I suppose you're interested also in all chars.

Answer (score 1):

Before C++20, you can wrap `std::integral_constant` with a macro to make `throw` trigger a compile error.

```
    constexpr uint16_t operator "" _int(const char* s, std::size_t len)
    {
        return len == 2 ? s[0] | (s[1] << 8) : throw;
    }

    void test()
    {
#define FORCE_CONSTANT(val) std::integral_constant<decltype(val), (val)>::value

        FORCE_CONSTANT("AB"_int);
        // FORCE_CONSTANT("ABC"_int); // error, expected compile-time constant expression
    }
```

And things become easy since C++20, user-defined literals are allowed to be `string literal operator template`. ([cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators))

So, the following code will work as you expect.

```
template <size_t kCount>
struct template_str_buffer
{
    using char_type = char;

    consteval template_str_buffer(const char_type(&str)[kCount]) noexcept
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < kCount; ++i) {
            data[i] = str[i];
        }
    }

    char_type data[kCount];
    constexpr static size_t count = kCount - sizeof(char_type);
};

template <template_str_buffer kStrBuf>
consteval uint16_t operator""_int()
{
    static_assert(kStrBuf.count == 2);
    return kStrBuf.data[0] | (kStrBuf.data[1] << 8);
}

void test()
{
    "AB"_int;
    // "ABC"_int; // static assertion failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

constexpr uint16_t operator "" _int(char const * s, size_t len)
{
    return (len == 2) ? s[0] | (s[1] << 8) : throw "len must be 2!";
}

int main()
{
    constexpr uint16_t i1 = "AB"_int; // OK
    cout << i1 << endl; // outputs 16961

    constexpr uint16_t i2 = "ABC"_int; // error
    cout << i2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:13:29:   in constexpr expansion of ‘operator""_int(((const char*)"ABC"), 3ul)’
prog.cpp:7:52: error: expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant-expression
     return (len == 2) ? s[0] | (s[1] << 8) : throw "len must be 2!";
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/qY7fn3)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's useful info that the OP apparently was unaware of, but it's not an answer. It should be a comment; flagged as such.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It DOES answer the question asked: "*How can I make `"ABC"_int` cause an error at compile time?*". Did you even try it? The error message is not nice looking, but it does only occur on `"ABC"_int`, `"AB"_int` compiles fine and outputs the desired output

Comment: The question is "How can I make "ABC"_int cause an error at compile time". Your attempted answer is that in one specific context, that of initializing a `constexpr` value, it causes error at compile time. The OP clearly asked for a general mechanism, not one particular special context.

Comment: So, you should *explain* what you have expressed with code (the single special context you could think of), and post that as a *comment*, and *delete* this attempted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was unfortunately not practical to post as a comment.

Fixes apart from making ungood literal a compile time error:

- Shift of signed values fixed.
- Use of `throw` without arguments.
- Assumption of 8-bit byte made explicit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>         // CHAR_BIT
using namespace std;

using Byte = unsigned char;
const int bits_per_byte = CHAR_BIT;

static_assert( bits_per_byte == 8, "!" );

constexpr auto operator "" _int( char const* s, std::size_t len )
    -> uint16_t 
{ return len == 2 ? Byte( s[0] ) | (Byte( s[1] ) << 8u) : throw "Bah!"; }

#define CHAR_PAIR( s ) static_cast<uint16_t>( sizeof( char[s ## _int] ) )

auto main()
    -> int
{
    CHAR_PAIR( "AB" );              // OK
    CHAR_PAIR( "ABC" );             //! Doesn't compile as ISO C++.
}
```

With Visual C++ that's all that's needed.

g++ is less standard-conforming in this respect, so for that compiler add option `-Werror=vla`.

With g++ you can alternatively use the following macro:

```
#define CHAR_PAIR( s ) []() constexpr { constexpr auto r = s##_int; return r; }()
```

This gives a more informative error message, but isn't supported by Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: So you're relying on the `throw` being an invalid expression for the ternary? That's clever.

Comment: On second glance, that's exactly what OP is doing. How is yours different?

Comment: @Mark: The three differences for the `operator""_int` implementation are listed in bullet points. The code shows how to get the compile time checking that the OP wants, but unfortunately not with his preferred syntax. That's why this isn't an answer either (a literal answer would just be, “Sorry, that's not possible”), but it's unfortunately not practical to cram all this into an SO comment.